# Drupal 7 programmatically create webform components

Tags: drupal-7, components, drupal-webform

I've followed this great [document](https://drupal.org/node/2030697) which successfully creates a webform and associated components.

I am trying to adjust the code so it works for existing webforms instead of creating new ones.
My code is as follows:

```
$nid = 12;

  $node = node_load(12);

  // Create the webform components.

  $components = array(

    array(

    'name' => 'Gender',

    'form_key' => 'gender',

    'type' => 'select',

    'mandatory' => 1,

    'weight' => 0,

    'pid' => 0,

    'extra' => array(

      'title_display' => 'inline',

      'private' => 0,

      'items' => "Mrs|Mrs\nMiss|Miss\nMr|Mr",

      'aslist' => 1,

    ),

  ),

  );

  // Setup notification email.

  $emails = array(

    array(

      'email' => 'somebody@example.tld',

      'subject' => 'default',

      'from_name' => 'default',

      'from_address' => 'default',

      'template' => 'default',

      'excluded_components' => array(),

    ),

  );

  // Attach the webform to the node.

  $node->webform = array(

    'confirmation' => '',

    'confirmation_format' => NULL,

    'redirect_url' => '<confirmation>',

    'status' => '1',

    'block' => '0',

    'teaser' => '0',

    'allow_draft' => '0',

    'auto_save' => '0',

    'submit_notice' => '1',

    'submit_text' => '',

    'submit_limit' => '-1', // User can submit more than once.

    'submit_interval' => '-1',

    'total_submit_limit' => '-1',

    'total_submit_interval' => '-1',

    'record_exists' => TRUE,

    'roles' => array(

      0 => '1', // Anonymous user can submit this webform.

    ),

    'emails' => $emails,

    'components' => $components,

  );

  // Save the node.

  node_save($node);
```

When I attempt to execute my code I get the following error:

> Error message SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'nid' cannot be null

Answer (score 2):

First try to print all the available values of $node.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($node);
echo "</pre>"'
exit;
```

check that you are getting value for `$node[nid]` or not.

Comment: The node definately exists